# Docker Error: standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Tags: linux, docker

Created docker file and image successfully build and contained is also created but status is exited.

Staus Exited in "docker ps -a"

Receiving an error while accessing the Docker and check logs also

standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Below are the details of file: Dockerfile and command

**Docker File:**

[Docker File Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an9cq.png)

**Docker Command detail and error**

[Docker Command Deails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQpHi.png)

Comment: No need to delete a question and recreate a new one to update it. Anyway, it looks like the issue comes from `entrypoint.sh` or `start.sh` if I'm not mistaken. Possible to post their content here?

Comment: **start.sh:**
#!/bin/bash
# start all the services
supervisord -n

**Enterypoint.sh:**
#!/bin/bash
set -e
exec "$@"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The container for your lamp image shows `"/entrypoint.sh /bin/"` as command, which fails.

I would update your ENTRYPOINT line in your Dockerfile to:

`ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]` as you did with CMD, build the image and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue. In my case it was because I was building my image on a windows machine. Windows adds "hidden characters" to files such as entrypoint.sh. To remove these characters you can run this command on the entrypoint.sh file after copying it into your container:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN dos2unix /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
```

now rebuild the image and try again. This solution worked for me.

You can read more about this anomaly here:

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/dos2unix-removing-hidden-windows-characters-from-files/